# Submenu doesn't render correctly on screen resize (and unexpected behaviour)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 5 links on my vertical nav. On screen resize my vertical nav becomes a horizontal nav with three (of those 5 links) showing and another link called `menu` which displays the other two remaining links.

For some reason, on screen resize, when `menu` appears, the list content is already displayed and then when menu is clicked, it leaves the hover properties even when you're not hovering over it. Here are visuals:

**1.** On screen resize, it appears like this:

[image]

**2.** When hovering over menu:

[image]

Which is OK. I only want the links to appear when the menu link is clicked, not hovered over. But I do not understand why `menu` talking up two `li` spaces.

**3.** When clicking menu:

[image]

This is OK. However, note how the Menu `li` is now perfectly sized.

**4.** After clicking on `menu` and then moving the mouse away from the link:
[image]

As mentioned, I do not know what's causing these issues.

Here is my current approach:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".show").click(function() {
    $(".subMenu").toggleClass("active");
    return false;
  });
});
```

```css
.site-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}


/* make divs appear below each other on screen resize */

@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  .site-wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

ul.subMenu {
  display: none;
}

.subMenu.active {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

li.show {
  display: none;
}

.nav-container {
  border-right: 1px solid #E4E2E2;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #f4f3f3;
}

.logo-holder {
  text-align: center;
}

.nav {
  text-align: justify;
}

nav:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.nav-link {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #f4f3f3;
}

.nav ul {
  width: 100%;
  /* make div span div */
  padding: 0px;
}

.nav ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav li:hover a {
  color: #f4f3f3;
}

.active {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #f4f3f3;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  .nav-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #f4f3f3;
    border-bottom: 0.5px solid #f4f3f3;
  }
  .nav-link {
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .logo-holder {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 40%;
  }
  .nav-container nav ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .logo-holder {
    text-align: left;
  }
  #navigation-div {
    background-color: #f4f3f3;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  .socials {
    display: none;
  }
  .hide {
    display: none;
  }
  .show {
    display: inline-block !important;
  }
  .nav ul li {}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="site-wrapper">
  <div class="nav-container">
    <div class="logo-holder">
      <img class="user-select-none" src="images/temp-logo.jpeg" alt="temp" />
    </div>
    <div id="navigation-div">
      <nav class="nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a class="nav-link active" href="">Test 1</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link " href="">Test 2</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link" href="">Test 3</a></li>
          <li class="hide"><a class="nav-link hide" href="">Test 4</a></li>
          <li class="hide"><a class="nav-link hide" href="">Test 5</a></li>
          <li class="show"><a class="nav-link" href="">Menu</a>
            <ul class="subMenu">
              <li><a class="nav-link" href="">Test 4</a></li>
              <li><a class="nav-link" href="">Test 5</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want something like Test 4 and Test 5 will be shown on Menu click only. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation:**

You have so many things messed up. Most important to note is that sub elements are inheriting from main elements. For example, if we have the following HTML:

```
<ul id="main_menu">
    <li>list item 1</li>
    <li>list item 2</li>
    <li>
         <ul id="sub_menu">
             <li>sub list item 1</li>
         </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And this CSS:

```
#main_menu li {/* This styling will also be applied to sub_menu!! */
    color: red;
}
```

So if you want to apply to **only direct li** under main menu, use `>` which means only direct elements, like so:

```
#main_menu > li {/* This styling will be applied only to direct li, sub_menu li will not take this styling */
    color: red;
}
```

**Fixing the problem:**

1- Add !important to sub menu:

```
ul.subMenu {
    display: none !important;
}
```

2- Comment or remove this line:

```
.nav li:hover a {
    /* color: #f4f3f3; */
}
```

3- Your sub menu is inheriting some unwanted styling from the main menu. Add these should fix it for you:

```
.subMenu a.nav-link {
    background-color: #f4f3f3;
    color: #333;
}
.subMenu a.nav-link:hover {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #f4f3f3;
}
.subMenu.active {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8n1e71ze/).

Answer (score 0):

> For some reason, on screen resize, when menu appears, the list content is already displayed

You can use jQuery's resize function to do stuff when you resize.

> But I do not understand why menu talking up two li spaces.

Menu is taking up two li spaces because it contains a ul that is two spaces wide which is forcing it's width.
Adding a width to the anchor tag will make it look a little better as it won't inherit the width from the li.
a.nav-link { width: 50px;}

> After clicking on menu and then moving the mouse away from the link.

Add a class to the parent of the submenu using jQuery so you can control styling.

Here's the code, hope it helps!

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".subMenu").addClass('hide');
    $(".show").click(function() {
        $(".show").toggleClass('active-parent');
    $(".subMenu").toggleClass("active");
    $(".subMenu").toggleClass("hide");
    return false;
  });
});
$(window).resize(function(){
    $(".subMenu").addClass('hide');
});
```

html

```
<div class="site-wrapper">
  <div class="nav-container">
    <div class="logo-holder">
      <img class="user-select-none" src="images/temp-logo.jpeg" alt="temp" />
    </div>
    <div id="navigation-div">
      <nav class="nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a class="nav-link active" href="">Test 1</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link " href="">Test 2</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link" href="">Test 3</a></li>
          <li class="hide"><a class="nav-link hide" href="">Test 4</a></li>
          <li class="hide"><a class="nav-link hide" href="">Test 5</a></li>
          <li class="show"><a class="nav-link" href="">Menu</a>
            <ul class="subMenu">
              <li><a class="nav-link" href="">Test 4</a></li>
              <li><a class="nav-link" href="">Test 5</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.site-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}


/* make divs appear below each other on screen resize */

@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  .site-wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

ul.subMenu {
  display: none;
}

.subMenu.active {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

li.show {
  display: none;
}

.nav-container {
  border-right: 1px solid #E4E2E2;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #f4f3f3;
}

.logo-holder {
  text-align: center;
}

.nav {
  text-align: justify;
}

nav:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.nav-link {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #f4f3f3;
}

.nav ul {
  width: 100%;
  /* make div span div */
  padding: 0px;
}

.nav ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav li:hover a {
  color: #f4f3f3;
}

.active {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #f4f3f3;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  .nav-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #f4f3f3;
    border-bottom: 0.5px solid #f4f3f3;
  }
  .nav-link {
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .logo-holder {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 40%;
  }
  .nav-container nav ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .logo-holder {
    text-align: left;
  }
  #navigation-div {
    background-color: #f4f3f3;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  .socials {
    display: none;
  }
  .hide {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav-container nav .hide{
      display: none;
  }
  .show {
    display: inline-block !important;
  }
  a.nav-link {
    width: 50px;
  }
  .active-parent a.nav-link {
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #333;
  }
  .nav ul li {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No 2.

You're setting both `ul` to display as flex, change it so it will only applied to parent `ul` only

```
  .nav-container nav>ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
  }
```

Cosmetic for your second level links when user click the menu

```
.selected a,
.active a {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #f4f3f3;
}
```

I also added some class to make styling easier when the menu is open

```
$(this).toggleClass('selected');
```

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".show").click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass('selected');
      $(".subMenu").toggleClass("active");
      return false;
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.site-wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}


/* make divs appear below each other on screen resize */

@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  .site-wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

ul.subMenu {
  display: none;
}

.subMenu.active {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

li.show {
  display: none;
}

.nav-container {
  border-right: 1px solid #E4E2E2;
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #f4f3f3;
}

.logo-holder {
  text-align: center;
}

.nav {
  text-align: justify;
}

nav:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.nav-link {
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 0px;
  padding-left: 15px;
}

.nav-link:hover {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #f4f3f3;
}

.nav ul {
  width: 100%;
  /* make div span div */
  padding: 0px;
}

.nav ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav>li:hover a {
  color: #f4f3f3;
}

.active {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #f4f3f3;
}

.selected a,
.active a {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #f4f3f3;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  .nav-container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #f4f3f3;
    border-bottom: 0.5px solid #f4f3f3;
  }
  .nav-link {
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .logo-holder {
    overflow: hidden;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 40%;
  }
  .nav-container nav>ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .logo-holder {
    text-align: left;
  }
  #navigation-div {
    background-color: #f4f3f3;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  .socials {
    display: none;
  }
  .hide {
    display: none;
  }
  .show {
    display: inline-block !important;
  }
  .nav ul li {}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="site-wrapper">
  <div class="nav-container">
    <div class="logo-holder">
      <img class="user-select-none" src="images/temp-logo.jpeg" alt="temp" />
    </div>
    <div id="navigation-div">
      <nav class="nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a class="nav-link active" href="">Test 1</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link " href="">Test 2</a></li>
          <li><a class="nav-link" href="">Test 3</a></li>
          <li class="hide"><a class="nav-link hide" href="">Test 4</a></li>
          <li class="hide"><a class="nav-link hide" href="">Test 5</a></li>
          <li class="show"><a class="nav-link" href="">Menu</a>
            <ul class="subMenu">
              <li><a class="nav-link" href="">Test 4</a></li>
              <li><a class="nav-link" href="">Test 5</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```